# Mute kinect commands

Tags: voice-recognition, kinect-sdk, mute

So I wrote the following code as a basic voice control code for my PC using the Kinect and it has been working well! But as soon as I tried to add in a sort of "mute" code, it stopped working. I figured out why it stopped working, but I can't figure out how to have it work with some kind of mute code and it's causing nose bleeds! I feel like the answer is simple and I just forgot how to do it or that I just haven't thought of it yet... that's what kills me.

Anyway, as you can see the problem is that the variable "listen" which is initialized later in the code, needs a starting value to be able to use it in if and switch statements. I have the starting value as 0 so that nothing will run until listen is set to 1, which only happens once I say "Hey Jarvis" (Inspired by Iron Man of course). However, as the code comes through a new cycle, it resets the variable "listen" back to zero because that's the value it was initialized in! I can't figure out a way to make that variable value flexible to my commands independent of how many cycles the code does. IT IS SO FRUSTRATING! If any of you can shed light on this I would be a very happy man. Feel free to make fun of any noob code you see if that helps... just please show me what my noob eyes fail to see!

```
namespace Speech
{
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading;
 using Microsoft.Kinect;
 using Microsoft.Speech.AudioFormat;
 using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Diagnostics;

 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        KinectSensor sensor = (from sensorToCheck in KinectSensor.KinectSensors where sensorToCheck.Status == KinectStatus.Connected select sensorToCheck).FirstOrDefault();
        if (sensor == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                    "No Kinect sensors are attached to this computer or none of the ones that are\n" +
                    "attached are \"Connected\".\n" +
                    "Attach the KinectSensor and restart this application.\n" +
                    "Make sure the Power Adapter of the Kinect sensor is plugged in \n" +
                    "Press any key to continue.\n");

            // Give a chance for user to see console output before it is dismissed
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return;
        } // end if (sensor == null)

        sensor.Start();

        // Obtain the KinectAudioSource to do audio capture
        KinectAudioSource source = sensor.AudioSource;
        source.EchoCancellationMode = EchoCancellationMode.None; // No AEC for this sample
        source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = false; // Important to turn this off for speech recognition

        RecognizerInfo ri = GetKinectRecognizer();

        if (ri == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find Kinect speech recognizer. Please refer to the sample requirements.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Using: {0}", ri.Name);

        // NOTE: Need to wait 4 seconds for device to be ready right after initialization
        int wait = 4;
        while (wait > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Device will be ready for speech recognition in {0} second(s).\r", wait--);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.Write("\n");     
//============================================================================       
        using (var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id))
        {
            var command = new Choices();

            //***************************************************
            command.Add("Hey Jarvis");
            command.Add("Open Videos");   
            command.Add("Parenthood");  
            command.Add("Down Ten"); 
            command.Add("Down Five");  
            command.Add("Down Three"); 
            command.Add("Down Two");  
            command.Add("Down One");  
            command.Add("Up Ten");
            command.Add("Up Five");
            command.Add("Up Three");
            command.Add("Up Two");
            command.Add("Up One");
            command.Add("Yes");
            command.Add("Full Screen");
            command.Add("Minimize");
            command.Add("Volume Up");
            command.Add("Volume Down");
            command.Add("Go Back");
            command.Add("Go Forward");
            command.Add("Pause");
            command.Add("Close Window");
            command.Add("Minimize");
            command.Add("Next");
            command.Add("Play");
            command.Add("Episode Sixteen");
            command.Add("Episode Seventeen");
            command.Add("Episode Eighteen");
            command.Add("Episode Nineteen");
            command.Add("Episode Twenty");
            command.Add("Episode Twenty One");
            command.Add("Episode Twenty Two");
            command.Add("Episode Twenty Three");
            command.Add("Episode Twenty Four");
            command.Add("Right");
            command.Add("Left");
            command.Add("Open Dark Souls");
            command.Add("No Steam");
            //***************************************************
            var gb = new GrammarBuilder { Culture = ri.Culture };

            // Specify the culture to match the recognizer in case we are running in a different culture.                                 
            gb.Append(command);

            // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
            var g = new Grammar(gb);                    

            sre.LoadGrammar(g);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += SreSpeechRecognized;
            // sre.SpeechHypothesized += SreSpeechHypothesized;
            // sre.SpeechRecognitionRejected += SreSpeechRecognitionRejected;

            using (Stream s = source.Start())
            {
                sre.SetInputToAudioStream(
                    s, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));

                Console.WriteLine("The System is actively monitoring Voice command ... \n");

                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            }
        }  // end using (var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id))
 //==========================================================================
        sensor.Stop();
    }  // end public static void Main

    private static RecognizerInfo GetKinectRecognizer()
    {
        Func<RecognizerInfo, bool> matchingFunc = r =>
        {
            string value;
            r.AdditionalInfo.TryGetValue("Kinect", out value);
            return "True".Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && "en-US".Equals(r.Culture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        };
        return SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers().Where(matchingFunc).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private static void SreSpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
       int listen=0;          //<<<<<<<< HERES THE PROBLEM
       if (e.Result.Confidence >= 0.7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSpeech Recognized: \t{0}\tConfidence:\t{1}", e.Result.Text, e.Result.Confidence);
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "Hey Jarvis":
                    Console.Write("                             Yes Gary?");
                    listen=1;
                    break;

                case "Open Videos":
                    Console.Write("Open Videos");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Parenthood":
                    Console.Write("Parenthood");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                        break;

                case "Down Ten":
                    Console.Write("Down Ten");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Down 10}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Down Five":
                    Console.Write("Down Five");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Down 5}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Down Three":
                    Console.Write("Down Three");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Down 3}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Down Two":
                    Console.Write("Down Two");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Down 2}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Down One":
                    Console.Write("Down One");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Down}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Up Ten":
                    Console.Write("Up Ten");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Up 10}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Up Five":
                    Console.Write("Up Five");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Up 5}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Up Three":
                    Console.Write("Up Three");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Up 3}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Up Two":
                    Console.Write("Up Two");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Up 2}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Up One":
                    Console.Write("Up One");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Up}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Yes":
                    Console.Write("Yes");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Full Screen":
                    Console.Write("Full Screen");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Exit":
                    Console.Write("Exit");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Volume Up":
                    Console.Write("Volume Up");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("^{Up}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Volume Down":
                    Console.Write("Volume Down");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("^{DOWN}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Go Back":
                    Console.Write("Go Back");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("%{LEFT}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Go Forward":
                    Console.Write("Go Forward");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("%{RIGHT}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Pause":
                    Console.Write("Pause");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Play":
                    Console.Write("Play");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Close Window":
                    Console.Write("Close Window");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Right":
                    Console.Write("Right");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Left":
                    Console.Write("Left");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{Left}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Sixteen":
                    Console.Write("Episode Sixteen");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 15}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Seventeen":
                    Console.Write("Episode Seventeen");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 16}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Eighteen":
                    Console.Write("Episode Eighteen");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 17}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Nineteen":
                    Console.Write("Episode Nineteen");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 18}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Twenty":
                    Console.Write("Episode Twenty");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 19}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Twenty One":
                    Console.Write("Episode Twenty One");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 20}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Episode Twenty Two":
                    Console.Write("Episode Twenty Two");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{p}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN 21}");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{f}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Minimize":
                    Console.Write("Minimize");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("% ");
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{n}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Next":
                    Console.Write("Next");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("%{TAB 2}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Open Dark Souls":
                    Console.Write("Open Dark Souls");
                    if (listen == 1) SendKeys.SendWait("{F7}");
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "No Steam":
                    Console.Write("No Steam");
                    if (listen == 1)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");
                    }
                    else Console.Write("                             Muted");
                    break;

                case "Thanks Jarvis":
                    Console.Write("                             You're Welcome");
                    listen = 0;
                    break;

            } // end switch (e.Result.Text) 
        }   // end if (e.Result.Confidence >= 0.7)
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSpeech Recognized but confidence was too low: \t{0}", e.Result.Confidence);
           // DumpRecordedAudio(e.Result.Audio);
        }

    } // end private static void SreSpeechRecognized


  } // end public class Program
} // end namespace Speech
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not encase your `switch` statement inside of another `switch`.

For example:

```
switch (listen)
{
    case 0:
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
               case "Hey Jarvis":
                   Console.Write("                             Yes Gary?");
                   listen=1;
                   break;
               case default:
                   Console.Write("                             Muted");
                   break;
         } 
         break;
    case 1:
           // All your normal code
}
```

Haven't used kinect-sdk before but I think the logic should still hold. I think what you have written is awesome and I will definitely look into using this for something.

You could alternatively return the value of listen from the `SreSpeechRecognized` method and instead of initialising it withing the method you could take it in as a parameter.

Comment: No bueno... your code left out the part where the variable listen is initialized with a value. Even if you say "Hey Jarvis" and set that value to 1 for your switch code, as soon as the code cycles you will lose that value and case 0 will remain default. I did try your code btw, just to make sure.